# i want to save token of signIn form in shared preference also reterive token successfull but did't saved

Tags: flutter, dart

For keep user logged in flutter app i want to save token from api response in SharedPreferences i trying to save but don't work

basically api response successfully received and its sigin token but how to save in sharedPreference for user loggedIn
after reopening the app i work on it but not saved pretty well

`````
here my splash screen method whereGoTo intiallzed in initState hook
 void whereGoTo() async {
    var sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var isSignedIn = sharedPref.getString('token');

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      if (isSignedIn != null && isSignedIn.isEmpty) {
        print(isSignedIn);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SafeArea(child: Login_Screen())));
      }
    });
  }
````here my signIn method integrated api and setString method to saved token after response of api`
String? myToken;
  loginApi(email, password) async {
    print(email);
    print(password);
    final response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse('https://quotes.limpidsol.com/api/login'), body: {
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('account loggedIn successfully');
      var data = ExtructData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      print(data.token);
      setState(() {
        myToken = data.token;
      });

      var pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      pref.setString('token', myToken!);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));

      String successMessage =
          'Logged in successfully. Status code: ${response.statusCode}';
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(successMessage),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      String errorMessage = 'Login failed. Status code: ${response.statusCode}';
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(errorMessage),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
`````

Answer (score 0):

Is there a right token value in `isSignedIn` parameter after this line `var isSignedIn = sharedPref.getString('token');`?

As I see in your code, mistake is in condition: instead of

```
if (isSignedIn != null && isSignedIn.isEmpty) {
```

should be

```
if (isSignedIn != null && isSignedIn.isNotEmpty) {
```

PS it's better to use some secure storage to store tokens - for example [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) package